# Simentenoulsy pass by value and pass by reference in python?

Tags: python, pointers

**Premise:**

Suppose I have a variable `x` and two function `f(x)` and `g(x)`
such that when `f(x)` has the ability to change the value of `x` (maybe it wants to keep track on how many times `f(x)` has been called) and `g(x)` doesn't want to change the value of x at any cost.

Now if i was choose `x` as an integer, I can accomplish `g(x)` and if `x` is a list, I can accomplish `f(x)`.

**Question:**

But what if I want to accomplish both of them in the same program?

What should I do then?.

If its not possible, then doesn't this severely handicap python wrt other languages.

**Note:**

Basically my question is motivated by finding the drawbacks of not having pointers in python as in other language like C++, the above task can easily be implemented by choosing the `*x` instead of `x`.

Comment: Maybe read http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/11/does-python-pass-by-value-or-by.html

Answer (score 1):

If all you need to do is change the value of a variable that you pass to `f`, you can simply return the new value:

```
def f(x):
    return x + 1

x = 30
x = f(x)
# x is now 31
```

If there is already another value you need to return from `f`, you can return a tuple and unpack the return value to multiple variables:

```
def f(x):
    return 46, x + 1

x = 30
y, x = f(x)
# x is now 31
```

In C++, the use of pointers that you bring up compensates for the fact that it's relatively difficult to return multiple values from a function. In Python, while we're still technically returning one value, it's much easier to create tuples and unpack them.

Comment: This is the Pythonic way: explicit is better than implicit.  If you're going to use a function to change a value use `=` and there's no confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your own class:

```
`class some_class():
   self._value = 0   
   self._access_counter = 0

 def update_value(self):
  <your code here>

 def get_value_by_ref(self):
  self._access_counter += 1
  return self._value
```

`

Comment: can you please provide a little more details and/or an example to express your point.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to have:
`class soem_class():
   self._value = 0   
   self._value_access = 0

 def update_value(self):
  <your code here>

 def get_value_by_pointer(self):

  self._value_access += 1
  return self._value `
``